# Need help simplifying a summation of combinations where the upper bound is a variable.

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

I am computing an expectation value by conditioning and have arrived at the following step:

\begin{equation}
   E[X] =\sum\limits_{x=1}^{11-N} x\cdot \frac{\binom{10-x}{N-1}}{\binom{10}{N}}
\end{equation}

I know that the final result should be $ \mathbb E\left[X\right]=\dfrac{11}{1+N}$, but I'm not sure how to simplify the expression above. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've made an edit. I've exchanged $n$ by $N$. A reply would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: More generally, $$\sum _{k=1}^{Q+1-N}k{Q-k\choose N-1}={Q+1\choose N+1}$$

Comment: @callculus42 Thank you for editing the question. Appreciate it.

Comment: @GEdgar Thank you! Is there a name for this property that I can look more into?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First note that
$$
\sum_{x=1}^{11-N} x\cdot \binom{10-x}{N-1}
= \sum_{x=1}^{11-N} \binom{x}{1}\binom{1}{1}\binom{10-x}{N-1}
= \binom{11}{N+1},
$$
which you can prove combinatorially by counting $(N+1)$-subsets of $\{1,\dots,11\}$ according to the second smallest element $x+1$. (Given $x+1$, there are $\binom{x}{1}$ choices for the smallest element and $\binom{10-x}{N-1}$ choices for the other $N-1$ elements that are larger than $x+1$.)

Then apply
$$\binom{11}{N+1} = \frac{11}{N+1}\binom{10}{N}$$ and simplify.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation.